# How to install bcmath module?

Tags: php, module, bcmath

How do I install the bcmath module on a server? I tried

```
yum update php-bcmath
```

but it said it found nothing.

Comment: https://github.com/phpseclib/bcmath_compat might be an option worth considering.

Answer (score 70):

Try `yum install php-bcmath`. 
If you still can't find anything, try `yum search bcmath` to find the package name

Comment: hi, i tried this along with the update but it did not work. but I did some search in google and found that centos doesnt have bcmath for the version of php i have on my server. so i think i am planning to find some other alternative.s thanks

Comment: Ok I supposed you had fedora... It would have been useful to specify your distribution in your question.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final) has php-bcmath

Comment: I had to go with `yum install php53u-bcmath` due to some conflicts.

Comment: In php7, `sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath`

Comment: This worked for me. Yum automatically detected the correct package for the php version I was using

Answer (score 68):

ubuntu and php7.1

```
sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

ubuntu and php without version specification

```
sudo apt install php-bcmath
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath

Comment: how do you install it in mac?

Comment: And (if using apache), `service apache2 reload` afterwards.  Otherwise bcmath won't yet be enabled.

Comment: I've hit a few servers where yum needs the CPU arch at the end of the package name, i.e. `php71-bcmath.x86_64`. Use `yum search bcmath` to see what options are available on your server.

Answer (score 12):

```
yum install php72-php-bcmath.x86_64
cp /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-bcmath.ini /etc/php.d/
cp /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/bcmath.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/
systemctl restart httpd
```

Not sure why I had to go so deep considering the yum install gave me bcmath in phpinfo()

Comment: Because you need php-bcmath (base package, from remi-php72) not php72-php-bcmath (SCL from remi-safe)

Comment: This solution worked for me. I am new to this. Can somebody explain this in details? Or provide a link where I can see more details.

Answer (score 11):

Worked great on CentOS 6.5

## yum install bcmath

All my calls to bcmath functions started working right after an apache restart

## service httpd restart

Sweet!

Answer (score 8):

When using the official PHP images of Docker, use `docker-php-ext-install bcmath`.

Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=description#php-core-extensions

Comment: Thank you SO much! It's been 5+ years since I've done any php, but I have since started using Docker for everything. I had to dig up a really old project and  I've been adding random PPA's and debs, trying to use PECL and a bunch of other things for hours. Composer install finally worked thanks to you!

Answer (score 6):

Was getting call to undefined function `bcmod()`

```
yum install php-bcmath
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

you should then see something similar to `/etc/php.d/bcmath.ini` listed under phpinfo.

```
Centos 7
Plesk 12
PHP 5.4.16
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed `php 7.1` 
then this line work on your system.

```
sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

check your php version in your system on `ubuntu 16.04`

```
php -v
```

and then result show there..

> PHP 7.1.x+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018
>   07:16:12) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me on Centos 7.4 with PHP 7.1 using remi repository.

First find out which PHP version I have:

```
[kiat@reporting ~]$ php --version
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2019 07:28:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Then search for `bcmath` extension in `remi-php71` repository:

```
[kiat@reporting ~]$ yum search php71 | grep bcmath
php71-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath
php71u-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath
```

Now install the first matching extension:

```
[kiat@reporting ~]$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php-bcmath
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
.
.
.
```

Finally, restart php and nginx:

```
[kiat@reporting ~]$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm nginx
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that the repo that had the package was not enabled. On OEL7,

```
$ vi /etc/yum.repos.d/ULN-Base.repo
Set enabled to 1 for ol7_optional_latest

$ yum install php-bcmath
```

and that worked...

I used the following command to find where the package was

```
$ yum --noplugins --showduplicates --enablerepo \* --disablerepo \*-source --disablerepo C5.\*,c5-media,\*debug\*,\*-source list \*bcmath
```

Comment: Worked on Debian.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable any extension then you have to install an extension first, extension maybe enabled but not installed, so taking the example of bcmath

1. yum search php-bcmath
2. Then ensure the php version in which u want to install this extension
3. You will get output like after yum search command>>

yum search php-bcmath**
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

```
EA4: 66.71.244.18
cpanel-addons-production-feed: 66.71.244.18
base: mirror.nodesdirect.com
epel: mirror.coastal.edu
extras: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
updates: mirror.jaleco.com
**============================================================== N/S matched: php-bcmath ===============================================================
ea-php54-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
ea-php55-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
ea-php56-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
ea-php70-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
ea-php71-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
ea-php72-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
```

6. If I wanna install for php71 then the command will be like **yum install ea-php71-php-bcmath.x86_64**  or yum install php71-bcmath.
7. You can install any extension from the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu PHP 7.3

```
sudo apt install php7.3-bcmath
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable `bcmath` in `Arch Linux` or `Manjaro`

Edit `php.ini`

```php
nano /etc/php/php.ini
```

Uncomment `bcmath` (remove semicolon)

```
extension=bcmath
```

If you are using Apache server reload the server by

```sh
sudo systemctl reload apache.server
```

Or

```sh
sudo systemctl realod httpd
```

If you don't use Apache

```sh
sudo systemctl reload php-fpm.service
```

To see the activated modules

```sh
php -m
```

To make sure the `bcmath` is installed and activated, search for it

```sh
php -m | grep bcmath
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `install php72-php-bcmath.x86_64`
Then,

```
systemctl restart php72-php-fpm.service
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7+ version you can use only:

```
sudo apt install php-bcmath
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried below package for php v5.6 and it worked for me.

```
yum install php56w-bcmath
```

Answer (score 0):

apt repo have this extension, just run the below command from your terminal ::

sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath*

Answer (score 0):

If still anyone is not getting how to install bcmath as it has lots of other dependant modules to install like php7.2-common, etc.

Try using synaptic application, to install the same. fire command.\

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open the synaptic application and then click on search tab.

search for `bcmath`

search results will show all the packages depends on php.

Install as per your convenience.

and install with all auto populated dependancies it required to install.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7 with php7.0

Install CentOS SCLo RH repository: `yum install centos-release-scl-rh`

Install rh-php71-php-bcmath rpm package: `yum install rh-php71-php-bcmath`

`systemctl restart httpd.service`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install PHP extensions in ubuntu.

first know which PHP version is active.

```
php -v
```

After that install needed plugin using this command.

```
sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath
```

you can replace php7.0-bcmath to `php-PHPVersion-extensionName`