# how to add bcmath extension in php 5.6 with php-fpm on Centos 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, bcmath

I am trying to add bcmath extension on my Centos 7 which has PHP 5.6 installed along with nginx and php-fpm

I ran

```
yum install php56-bcmath
```

Above installed the bcmath extension which I can see under the 'module' column in phpinfo() output.

However when I call php function **get_loaded_extensions**, I don't see the bcmath in the loaded extension list.

I restarted php-fpm and nginx after installing bcmath package.

Am I missing anything?

output of get_loaded_extensions()

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => zlib
    [7] => filter
    [8] => hash
    [9] => Reflection
    [10] => SPL
    [11] => session
    [12] => standard
    [13] => cgi-fcgi
    [14] => bz2
    [15] => calendar
    [16] => ctype
    [17] => curl
    [18] => dom
    [19] => mbstring
    [20] => fileinfo
    [21] => ftp
    [22] => gd
    [23] => gettext
    [24] => iconv
    [25] => exif
    [26] => mcrypt
    [27] => mysqlnd
    [28] => PDO
    [29] => Phar
    [30] => posix
    [31] => shmop
    [32] => SimpleXML
    [33] => sockets
    [34] => sqlite3
    [35] => sysvmsg
    [36] => sysvsem
    [37] => sysvshm
    [38] => tokenizer
    [39] => xml
    [40] => xmlwriter
    [41] => xsl
    [42] => mysql
    [43] => mysqli
    [44] => pdo_mysql
    [45] => pdo_sqlite
    [46] => wddx
    [47] => xmlreader
    [48] => json
    [49] => zip
    [50] => mhash
)
```

Comment: Can you please post what you got within get_loaded_extensions?

Comment: @Kamal The output is added now in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the probem.

I had multiple installations of PHP

There was a php56 version installed too which was being used by the php-fpm. So I installed bcmath library using the command below and it then got applied to the correct PHP installation.

```
yum install php56-php-bcmath
```

restarted php-fpm and there was the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicated] Some solutions in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400362/how-to-install-bcmath-module)

Comment: Not sure why above extensions are required, I did not find much information on them being related to bcmath. If someone can confirm that would be great.

Comment: In debian i install those extensions before installing bcmath and every think work fine. I updated the responce

Comment: I have already tried what is suggested on the stackoverflow (by the link posted i your answer) and none of those solution works.