# RuntimeException: The bcmath extension is required by NumberFormatter

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I have installed drupal commerce module. I am getting the below error while viewing a product page.

```
RuntimeException: The bcmath extension is required by NumberFormatter. in CommerceGuys\Intl\Formatter\NumberFormatter->__construct() (line 113 of /home/web/docroot/vendor/commerceguys/intl/src/Formatter/NumberFormatter.php).
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400362/how-to-install-bcmath-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have bcmath error and you need to install PHP bcmath extension.

`sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath`

You can check enabled extensions with php function. `get_loaded_extensions()`

Answer (score 0):

Install php-bcmath with dependencies

**yum install php-bcmath**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your PHP version you have to install bcmath extension.

for 7.2

```
 sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath
```

for 7.4

```
 sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath
```

Once done with installation you have to restart apache server then only it will start.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```