# I installed bcmath, but I can't get my laravel project find it

Tags: php, laravel, bcmath

I am working on a Laravel project using the auth scaffolding. When trying the link "forgot your password" with a valid mail address, I get the following error:

```
The BCMath functions must be enabled to use the NTLM authenticator.
```

Following other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400362/how-to-install-bcmath-module), I installed the bcmath module for my PHP version (7.2) using:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath
```

Then I restarted apache. I can see bcmath listed when using `php -m`, but still the error in my project. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you restarted the Apache/Nginx?

Comment: have you checked the fpm version of php. the extension might not be active there(different php.ini)

Comment: And if you did: run a `phpinfo()` to see which PHP version and extensions you're using. It might be that your web server is using a different PHP install.

Comment: I restarted Apache, and I am effectively working with PHP 7.2. I will investigate fpm