# How to install BCMath in PHP 7.3 on Windows

Tags: php

How can I install this extension on my windows 10 using `php 7.3`?
I looked in some forums, however in my php.ini there is no = php_bcmath.dll written.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php

Comment: Like the in the link shared by @mario, you don't see BCmath in phpInfo() ? Are you using php in a standalone version or distributed with a local server like (XAMPP, WAMP,UWamp,Laragon...) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install bcmath module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400362/how-to-install-bcmath-module)

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php

> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension. You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use these functions.